# Sobrenomes em citações de revistas internacionais

Tags: português-brasileiro, nomes

Bom dia a todos.

Imaginemos que um rapaz chamado *Henrique Ferreira da Silva* está no início de sua carreira acadêmica e deseja saber como escrever seu nome em jornais internacionais. Se ele publica um artigo sozinho e escreve como autor seu nome completo, os indexadores automáticos de referências vão naturalmente considerá-lo em uma das seguintes formas:

> Ferreira da Silva, Henrique

> da Silva, Henrique Ferreira

> Silva, Henrique Ferreira da

- O que é mais recomendado de se fazer no caso do nosso amigo imaginário? Escolher um sobrenome e assinar como se não houvessem outros?
- Qual o sobrenome você escolheria?

As normas da ABNT não devem determinar esta escolha, mas podem influenciar já que o nosso amigo poderia se interessar em publicar em revistas brasileiras também...

Agora, compliquemos a situação e suponhamos que o pai do nosso amigo tenha o mesmo nome que ele. No Brasil é comum nestes casos acrescentar "Filho" ou "Júnior" no fim do nome. Suponhamos então que nosso amigo se chama *Henrique Ferreira da Silva Júnior*. O que fazer? Esquecer o "Júnior" e assinar sem? Assinar como "da Silva Júnior" (ou mesmo "da Silva Jr.") mesmo sabendo que algum estrangeiro mal informado pode citar o seu artigo como "Júnior, H."?

Eu mesmo estou nesta situação. Tenho "Júnior" no fim do meu nome e escolhi adotar o formato "último sobrenome + Júnior", mas não sei se foi uma boa escolha. Eu não tenho "da" no meu último sobrenome, então meu caso não é tão ruim quanto o do nosso amigo hipotético. Estou pensando em começar a assinar meus artigos com Jr. no fim, talvez desta forma os desavisados sejam forçados acrescentar meu último sobrenome antes de "Jr.".

A propósito do meu caso, podemos pensar que me chamo Tadeu Correia Melo Júnior. Escolhi assinar como "Tadeu Melo Júnior" ou "T. Melo Júnior" e estive pensando em assinar "T. Melo Jr." nos próximos artigos. Qual a opinião de vocês?

Comment: Tenho ciência de que esta pergunta seja possivelmente inadequada ao fórum. Não hesitem em mover a questão ou sugerir outro fórum mais adequado dentro da rede StackExchange.

Comment: Filburt, não há um editor em tua instituição de ensino? Nos artigos científicos que vi, é sempre nome completo normal, como em “João Alberto Ferreira Júnior”. Apenas vi mudarem a ordem em frases como “a vingança nunca é plena, mata a alma e a envenena” — Madruga, Seu. Nesse último exemplo, “seu” seria o nome e “Madruga” seria o sobrenome. Este documento também diz apenas para colocar o nome do autor: http://ava.grupouninter.com.br/tead/pos/trabalhodeconclusaodecurso/Documentos/Anexo%202%20-%20Modelo%20Artigo%20Cientifico.pdf.

Comment: Sobre revistas nacionais ou internacional, sempre ouvi que cada revista tem seu próprio modo. Então, talvez o jornal Batatas Lunares escreva “Fernando Henrique” e o jornal Queijo Eterno escreva “Henrique, Fernando”. Não sou da área e tudo o que disse é o que ouvi de que é dela ou o que eu vi.

Comment: bem-vindo ao site. Parece-me ser uma pergunta sobre formatação, o que creio que seja correto aqui. O ponto de formatação é que varia bastante inclusive de artigo para artigo da mesma área. Claro, a grande maioria é igual, mas há bastante variação de ESTILO.

Comment: Obrigado pelos comentários @Schilive. Fico feliz que o tema pareça estar dentro da proposta do site, mas a questão que eu gostaria de levantar não é sobre formatação e sim sobre a escolha que eu tenho de como quero escrever meu nome num artigo que escrevi. Isso eu quem decido e gostaria saber de vocês sobre as possibilidades e quais os pontos positivos e negativos de cada uma. No caso do nome Henrique Ferreira da Silva Júnior as possibilidades seriam: (1) eliminar "da Silva Júnior" e assinar como "Henrique Ferreira"; (2) eliminar "Henrique"; (3) eliminar "Henrique" e "Júnior; (4) outra?

Comment: E só para dar um contexto, tomemos como exemplo este artigo aleatório que encontrei: https://arxiv.org/pdf/2101.12716.pdf

Aparentemente a pessoa colocou um hífen entre os seus sobrenomes no intuito de colá-los forçadamente. Neste caso, alguém que for citar o trabalho deste autor será obrigado a pegar seus dois nomes (por exemplo: "... segundo García-Heveling [13], ...). No meu caso talvez ficasse estranho colocar um hífen para ligar "Melo-Júnior", não sei...

Outra coisa, claro que, depois de escolher uma forma de assinar meus artigos, esta escola deve ser constante em todos eles.

Comment: Na verdade nomes com hifens são comuns em várias línguas, mas, sim, também é uma estratégia usada para 'forçar' as revistas a usar os dois nomes.

Comment: @stafusa obrigado por remarcar, eu ia colocar essa afirmação como hipótese mas tive que apagar porque passou do máximo de caracteres. :-)

Comment: Filburt, por curiosidade, dado o exemplo "Tadeu Correia Melo Júnior", qual é a sua escolha de nome para publicações?

Comment: @stafusa Assinei Tadeu Correia Melo Júnior no meu primeiro artigo, mas depois das primeiras citações percebi meu problema (já me citaram como "... by Júnior [13] .... ") Daí tomei o cuidado de colocar Melo Júnior no ORCID e nos sites das revistas e tenho mais dois artigos com outros autores onde eu assinei T. Melo Júnior. Finalmente tenho mais dois artigos (um deles sozinho) ainda não submetidos. Seria a minha chance de assinar Melo-Junior ou Melo-Jr. definitivamente, mas ainda não decidi. Talvez fique com Melo Júnior mesmo, já que já tenho dois artigos importantes com esse nome. O que acha?

Comment: Como você já tem artigo publicado, é mais difícil decidir. O conselho de fato é não mudar mais, mas, com bases como o ORCID isso é provavelmente menos crítico. E, pode depender da área, mas, em geral, usar "T. Melo Júnior" não garante que os dois sobrenomes sejam usados, quer pelas revistas, quer por outros autores te citando (e nem toda revista aceita abreviar o primeiro nome). Ou seja, há razões para se considerar adotar o hífen. Um detalhe: de qualquer forma eu manteria a inicial do Correia, para tornar o nome todo mais único. Se eu fosse permanecer publicando, adotaria "T. C. Melo-Jr".

Comment: @stafusa Obrigado pelo conselho. Estou pensando em "Melo Jr." sem o hífen, não é uma mudança tão grande em relação à "Melo Júnior" presente nos dois últimos artigos (o primeiro artigo honestamente é menos importante). Também não acho que alguém me citaria como "... a result from Jr. [13] ...", espero que não! Sobre o Correia, decidi aboli-lo completamente. Eu só o insiro no campo middle name quando existe, mas como geralmente pede-se given name et surname, ele é pouco utilizado. E nos artigos ele não aparece mais.

Comment: Acho um meio-termo aceitável. Esteticamente talvez "Jr" sem ponto seja melhor para um nome, mas o ponto tem a vantagem de diminuir a chance de citarem apenas "Jr.". Boa sorte e boas publicações!

Comment: @stafusa você também, e obrigado pela ajuda! Realmente me auxiliou na decisão. :-) (ps.: aparentemente ninguém se chama Tadeu Correia Melo Júnior, então acho que esse exemplo serviu bem para os propósitos da discussão...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essa é uma pergunta que se encaixa melhor no [Academia SE](https://academia.stackexchange.com/), sob a *tag* "[personal-name](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/personal-name)", mas talvez seja válido ter essa informação em português.

Alguns pontos gerais básicos:

- se registre no [ORCID](https://orcid.org/), e use seu número em todas as publicações onde isso for possível, pois assim a identificação correta fica mais garantida;
- quando escolher um nome base (sem abreviação do primeiro e último nomes), é consenso que ele deve ser mantido ao longo de toda a carreira;
- mesmo registrado no ORCID é vantajoso ter um nome menos comum, por conta das buscas por nome;
- embora não seja indispensável, é uma boa ideia omitir o acento em "Júnior" - os problemas em formulários estrangeiros são bem menos comuns que há alguns anos, mas ainda acontecem;
- o sistema de publicações internacional em geral é centrado no inglês, em que se esperam nomes no formato [1o nome / prenome] [iniciais do meio] [sobrenome]: satisfazer essa expectativa evita confusões em publicações, congressos, etc.

Fora essas recomendações, há bastante liberdade de escolha, uma vez que não se pedem comprovações e, de qualquer forma, pseudônimos em geral não são um problema.

No caso de um nome como "Tadeu Correia Melo Júnior" eu sugeriria, caso se queira manter o "Júnior", adotar "Correia-Melo-Jr", "Melo-Junior", ou "Melo-Jr".

Comment: Posso omitir o último nome e usar o do meio?

Comment: Olá, boas-vindas ao Portuguese SE. Obrigado pela contribuição, mas note que sua resposta é uma nova pergunta e assim foge ao formato da plataforma: que é **uma** pergunta seguida de respostas à pergunta — diferente de um fórum de discussão ou chat. Com relação à sua dúvida: Sim, pode — como menciono na resposta, até pseudônimos costumam não ser um problema. Considere também as demais sugestões, como ser consistente.